# can't read or write cookies js or something

Tags: javascript, cookies

I can't seem to set a cookie right, or maybe I'm not reading it correctly.

alert(m) = `name=Player; pl={"inf":0,"pop":0,"empty":{}}; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2015 00:00:01 GMT; path=/;`

alert(cs) = `name=Player ?`

not sure why cs doesn't equal m

```
save: function(){
    //erase cookies
    document.cookie = 'name=Player; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';


    var pl = "pl=" + JSON.stringify( this.player.getAsJSON() );
    var ex = "expires=Thu, 01 Jan 2015 00:00:01 GMT";
    var path = "path=/";

    var m = "name=Player; " + pl + "; " + ex + "; " + path + "; ";
    alert(m);

    //create new cookie
    document.cookie = m;
},

getSave: function(){
    var cs = document.cookie; 
    alert( cs );
    /*var parts = cs.split("; ");*/

}
```

Comment: _“alert(cs) only yields name=Player”_ – that’s the name and the value of the cookie, and therefor correct; you don’t get the rest of the parameters from `document.cookie`. (Be aware though, that when you set more than one cookie, they will be in `document.cookie` as well.)

Comment: So you're saying that a cookie only holds one pair of info?  I was thinking I could have as much info per cookie that I wanted.

I mean now I know I can use as many cookies that I wanted. or I can store a lot of info in 1 pair, but I just thought I could use several name=value pairs?

Thank you

Comment: For each key-value pair you want to save, you just set `document.cookie = cookieString;` for each pair. Retrieving them is just a matter of going through all the cookies set inside `document.cookie` like you have commented out.